# Redirect from Salesforce to external site on JS button click

Tags: javascript

Use Case : Need to redirect user to Active Directory Page from Salesforce on button click

```
function viewUserData() {

        sforce.console.getEnclosingPrimaryTabId(openSubtabs);
        sforce.console.getFocusedSubtabId(closeSubtab);
    }

    var openSubtabs = function openSubtabs(result) {

        var parentID = document.getElementById("viewUData").value;

        var url = 'https://userdata.repository.worklist_1000324.jsp?~|_E~|_~|_pvUserId~|_Need to put dynamic value here~|_~|_;

        var primaryTabId = result.id;
        sforce.console.openSubtab(primaryTabId ,'/'+url, true, 
            'View User data', null);
    };
```

Trials -
Tried querying Account number from Account object

```
var customerNumber = 'SELECT Customer_Number__c FROM Account WHERE Id = '+parentID+' LIMIT 1;
```

OR

```
sforce.connection.sessionId = '{!$Api.Session_ID}';
var CN = sforce.connection.query("Select  Customer_Number__c FROM Account Where Id ='"+ parentID +"'");
```

Any other solution?

Comment: Is the query the problem, or opening the tab? It doesn't seem clear to me what you're trying to do.

Comment: I am stuck at querying the field from Account by using the Account id.